# Get data from DB in Model or Helper. Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I need delete image from `media/modelname/othername/imagename.jpg` in my model `CompanyName_ProductName_Model_ModelName`.

Name of image located in db but when i try select data from db it return me empty array. There is my code

```
Mage::getModel('productlabels/block')->load($id)->getData();
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Plumrocket_Productlabels>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Plumrocket_Productlabels>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <productlabels>
            <class>Plumrocket_Productlabels_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>productlabels_resource</resourceModel>
        </productlabels>
        <productlabels_resource>
            <class>Plumrocket_Productlabels_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <table_labels>
                    <table>plumrocket_product_labels</table>
                </table_labels>
                <category_check_list>
                    <table>plumrocket_label_category</table>
                </category_check_list>
                <product_check_list>
                    <table>plumrocket_label_product</table>
                </product_check_list>
            </entities>
        </productlabels_resource>
    </models>
     <resources>
        <productlabels_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Plumrocket_Productlabels</module>
            </setup>
        </productlabels_setup>
    </resources>
    <helpers>
    <productlabels>
        <class>Plumrocket_Productlabels_Helper</class>
    </productlabels>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
         <productlabels>
             <class>Plumrocket_Productlabels_Block</class>
         </productlabels>
    </blocks>
</global>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
            <observers>
                <productlabels>
                    <class>productlabels/observer</class>
                    <method>addLabel</method>
                </productlabels>
            </observers>
        </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
        <admin_system_config_changed_section_productlabels>
            <observers>
                <productlabels>
                    <class>productlabels/observer</class>
                    <method>changeConfig</method>
                </productlabels>
            </observers>
        </admin_system_config_changed_section_productlabels>
    </events>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <productlabels before="Mage_Adminhtml">Plumrocket_Productlabels_Adminhtml</productlabels>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<default>
    <productlabels>
        <global>
            <enabled>1</enabled>
        </global>
    </productlabels>
</default>
```

my modules

```
class Plumrocket_Productlabels_Model_Block extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('productlabels/block');
}

protected function _afterDelete()
{   
    // here i need delete image
    return parent::_afterDelete();
}

public function setStatus($status)
{
    $this->setData('status', $status);
    return $this;
}

public function setFromData($fromdata)
{
    $this->setData('from_data', $fromdata);
    return $this;
}

public function setToData($todata)
{
    $this->setData('to_data', $todata);
    return $this;
}

public function setProductPagePosition($position)
{
    $this->setData('product_page_position', $position);
    return $this;
}

public function setCategoryPagePosition($position)
{
    $this->setData('category_page_position', $position);
    return $this;
}
```

}

```
class Plumrocket_Productlabels_Model_Resource_Block extends 
Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract 
{

public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('productlabels/table_labels','id_label');
}
```

}

```
class Plumrocket_Productlabels_Model_Resource_Block_Collection extends 
Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{

public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('productlabels/block');
}

public function getTitle()
{   
    $data = $this->getData();
    foreach ($data as $key ) {
        $result[$key['id_label']] = $key['title'];
    }
    array_unshift($result, " ");
    return $result;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please share some more code?

Comment: other part of code just need delete image unlink($path), path located in db

Comment: If `load($id)->getData()` doesnt work there's something wrong ... but w/o any code it's hard to telll ...

Comment: but if i do  the same code in some block it will be work correctly

Comment: Please, provide your config.xml and and your module triads code

Comment: Look above, please. I shared my config.xml and module triads code

Answer (score 0):

You can delete only the entry in the database about the path to the image, physically the image will remain on your disk.

```
$data = Mage::getModel('productlabels/block')->getCollection()->load($id)->getData();
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: No, if i select path from database i could delete image by using unlink($path)

Comment: $data = Mage::getModel('productlabels/block')->getCollection()->load($id)->getData();
var_dump($data);

Comment: it return null in Model_Block and Helper_Data but in any Block it work corectly, i dont know why

Comment: Do you want to delete the image directly in the model?

Comment: It not necessury

Comment: If I solved your problem, mark my answer as the best.

Comment: Ok, if my problem will solved i mark your answer as the best

Comment: Wait, what's wrong? You get a collection, take a link and delete it.

Comment: getData('product_label_image') it need to return me path to file and i delete it

Comment: method _afterDelete() in Plumrocket_Productlabels_Model_Block need containst logic